# Google sheets IF stops working correctly when wrapped in ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want this formula to calculate a date based on input from two other dates. I first wrote it for a single cell and it gives the expected results but when I try to use ARRAYFORMULA it returns the wrong results.

I first use two if statements specifycing what should happen if either one of the inputs is missing. Then the final if statement calculates the date if both are present based on two conditions. This seems to work perfectly if I write the formula for one cell and drag it down.

=IF( (LEN(G19)=0);(U19+456);(IF((LEN(U19)=0) ;(G19);(IF((AND((G19<(U19+456));(G19>(U19+273)) ));(G19);(U19+456))))))

However, when I want to use arrayformula to apply it to the entire column, it always returns the value_if_false if neither cell is empty, regardless of whether the conditions in the if statement are actually met or not. I am specifically talking about the last part of the formula that calculates the date if both input values are present, it always returns the result of U19:U+456 even when the result should be G19:G. Here is how I tried to write the ARRAYFORMULA:

={"Date deadline";ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN(G19:G400)=0);(U19:U400+456);(IF((LEN(U19:U400)=0);
(G19:G400);(IF((AND((G19:G400<(U19:U400+456));(G19:G400>(U19:U400+273)) ));(G19:G400);(U19:U400+456)))))))}

I am a complete beginner who only learned to write formulas two weeks ago, so any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can test this in a little bit but my initial instinct is you may need to anchor your ranges. As in $G19, $U19, etc... That being said what do your cells in G19:G400 look like? U19:U400? Are they dates? Is everything a date and you're simply adding days (456, 273) to dates?

Comment: AND and OR are not compatible with ARRAYFORMULA. I posted an answer, test it. If there is an error, pls give as aspreadsheet with sample tests.

Answer (score 0):

`AND` and `OR` are not compatible with `ARRAYFORMULA`

Replace them by `*` or `+`

Try

```
={"Date deadline";ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((LEN(G19:G400)=0),(U19:U400+456),
  (IF((LEN(U19:U400)=0), (G19:G400),
   (IF((((G19:G400<(U19:U400+456))*(G19:G400>(U19:U400+273)) )),(G19:G400),
    (U19:U400+456)))
  ))
 )
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you cannot use `AND`, `OR` operators in an `arrayformula`, so you must find an alternative method such as multiplying the values together and checking them for 0 or 1 (true*true=1)

I am gathering based on your formula's and work that you want to have the following:

1. If G19 is blank show U19 + 456
2. If U19 is blank show G19
3. If G19 is less than U19 + 456 but greater than U19 + 273 show G19
4. Otherwise show U19 + 456

I'm not too sure what you want to happen when both columns G and U are empty. Based on your current formula you are returning an empty cell + 456... but with this formula it returns an empty cell rather than Column U + 456

**Formula**

`={"Date deadline";ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFS((($G19:$G400="")*($U19:$U400=""))>0,"",$G19:$G400="",$U19:$U400+456,$U19:$U400="",$G19:$G400,(($G19:$G400<$U19:$U400+456)*($G19:$G400>$U19:$U400+273))>0,$G19:$G400,TRUE,$U19:$U400+456))))}`